# Using Jetty 9 as Java 9 Modules gives ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jetty, java-9, java-module

I use jetty 9.4.8.v20171121 with Java 9 and this is list of jetty modules I load:

```
jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
jetty-servlets-9.4.8.v20171121.jar 
jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar   
jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar 
jetty-http-9.4.8.v20171121.jar   
jetty-io-9.4.8.v20171121.jar 
jetty-security-9.4.8.v20171121.jar   
jetty-webapp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar
```

This is the code I start Jetty:

```
Server server = new Server( 8080 );
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath( "/" );
File warFile = new File(
        "/home/Sam/WebServer/jar/org.test.site.fend-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" );
if (!warFile.exists())
{
    throw new RuntimeException( "Unable to find WAR File: "
            + warFile.getAbsolutePath() );
}
webapp.setWar( warFile.getAbsolutePath() );
webapp.setExtractWAR(true);
webapp.setAttribute(
        "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
        ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/[^/]*taglibs.*\\.jar$" );
server.setHandler( webapp );
server.start();
server.dumpStdErr();
```

And this is what I get:

```
2018-02-06 17:18:03:111 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - starting o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@659499f1{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/Sam/WebServer/jar/org.test.site.fend-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war}
2018-02-06 17:18:03:115 [main] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@659499f1{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/Sam/WebServer/jar/org.test.site.fend-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at jetty.util@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:65)
    at jetty.webapp@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.loadConfigurations(WebAppContext.java:1035)
    at jetty.webapp@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:473)
    at jetty.webapp@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:544)
    at jetty.util@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at jetty.util@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at jetty.server@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at jetty.util@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at jetty.server@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at jetty.server@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at jetty.util@9.4.8.v20171121/org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The jars for Jetty 9.4.8 are not JPMS modules.  Perhaps a future Jetty 10.x (or more likely Jetty 11.x) will be the first JPMS Jetty release.

Comment: Don't know how long, to support JPMS properly would require a radical change in our packaging, and will definitely impact major parts of the codebase.  Then there's the missing parts of the JPMS spec with regards to how JEP238 and ServiceLoader behaviors are to work.  So, uhm, unlikely to see a release of Jetty+JPMS until Java 11 (at least).

Comment: There's also no support (that the Jetty devs know about) for annotation / bytecode scanning when using JPMS.   Feel free to open an issue asking about this at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt nice comments, but they would be rather useful wrapped up in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jars for Jetty 9.x (regardless of sub-version) are not [JPMS modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/).

In order for Jetty to properly support JPMS, it would require a radical change in the packaging and will definitely impact major parts of the Jetty codebase.

*Note: If you have a desire to see Jetty be fully JPMS compliant, please comment on issue https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2189*

Some things left to resolve before the JPMS effort in Jetty can proceed in earnest.

1. How does JEP238 (Multi-Release Jars) work with ServiceLoader behaviors? (hint: it currently doesn't)
2. How does Annotation / Bytecode scanning work in a Module environment? (current thinking is that we need to implement the same visibility rules that JPMS has and only scan what can be seen from the scope of the interested party: webapp or server)

As for when Jetty will support JPMS, that's unlikely to ever occur with Jetty 9.x, it was briefly discussed for Jetty 10.x but it was determined that supporting Servlet 4.0, javax.websocket 1.1, and Java 8 were still important.

Once Java 8 is fully end of life, the process of migrating existing stable branches to JPMS are valid. (if that will happen is a different question).

We are keeping an eye on the open questions we have with the spec groups, and also targeting the Java 11 (LTS) release as a good candidate for JPMS support.  That is likely to coincide with a (currently theoretical) Jetty 11.x as well.

Comment: JPMS support issue - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2191